'The request is not supported' error during 'BCryptExportKey'
I'm trying to use BCrypt crypto operation (BCryptEncrypt, BCryptDecrypt).
Before running encryption, decryption, I wanted to export and import the key.
I'm getting an error when trying to use 'BCryptExportKey'.
Found status code was 3221225659 (Hex - C00000BB).
This NTSTATUS code means "The request is not supported." (0xC00000BB - STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED)
Ref : NTSTATUS
But I can't figure out why this problem occurred.
I haven't found any resources/documentation related to this problem.
Could anyone help me with this?
Code:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExportImportKey();
        }

        internal static void ExportImportKey()
        {
            string keyString = "12345678abcdefgh";  // 16 byte
            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
            byte[] exportedKey = ExportKey(key);
        }

        internal static byte[] ExportKey(byte[] key)
        {
            IntPtr phAlgorithm = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hKey = IntPtr.Zero;
            byte[] exportedKey = null;

            uint statusCode = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(out phAlgorithm, "AES", "Microsoft Primitive Provider", 0);
            statusCode = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(phAlgorithm, out hKey, IntPtr.Zero, 0, key, key.Length, 0);
            int keySize = 0;
            statusCode = BCryptExportKey(hKey, IntPtr.Zero, "ECCPUBLICBLOB", null, 0, out keySize, 0);
            exportedKey = new byte[keySize];
            statusCode = BCryptExportKey(hKey, IntPtr.Zero, "KeyDataBlob", exportedKey, exportedKey.Length, out keySize, 0);

            return exportedKey;
        }

        [DllImport("bcrypt.dll")]
        public static extern uint BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(out IntPtr phAlgorithm, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszAlgId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszImplementation, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("bcrypt.dll")]
        public static extern int BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(IntPtr phAlgorithm, int dwFlags);

        [DllImport("bcrypt.dll")]
        public static extern uint BCryptExportKey(IntPtr hKey, IntPtr hExportKey, string pszBlobType, byte[] pbOutput, int cbOutput, out int pcbResult, int dwFlags);

        [DllImport("bcrypt.dll")]
        public static extern uint BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(IntPtr phAlgorithm, out IntPtr phKey, IntPtr pbKeyObject, int cbKeyObject, byte[] pbSecret, int cbSecret, int dwFlags);
    }
}

The provided status code was found after calling the first 'BCryptExportKey' in the given code.

The status error is explained at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptexportkey. But why are you using Interop rather than the native cryptography classes?
